# pam : how to restrict rules to non-root users

Tags: linux, pam

Starting with my original pam.d/login file :

```
auth            include         system-local-login
account         include         system-local-login
password        include         system-local-login
session         optional        pam_lastlog.so
session         include         system-local-login
```

I need, as an option, the service of additional MODULE (let's say pam_kwallet5.so as an example)

```
auth        include     system-local-login

auth        optional    MODULE

account     include     system-local-login
password    include     system-local-login
session     optional    pam_lastlog.so
session     include     system-local-login

session     optional    MODULE PARAMs
```

This achieves the goal as expected.

However, I now would lik to restrict this option to non-root users.

(let's say for example that, as root will never ever start kde, launching the kwalletd5 daemon at login serves no purpose)

I tried to find my way via the pam_listfile.so module but in vain.

---

**EDIT 1** : Wondering wether creating a pseudo-conditionnal entry thanks to pam_exec.so in [the way described here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/452530/how-to-create-a-conditional-pam-entry) could be an acceptable solution.

---

**EDIT 2** : Before discovering muru's better solution, I had managed to find a way thanks to pam_succeed_if.so used as follows :

```
auth        include                    system-local-login

auth        [default=1 success=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so uid > 0
auth        optional                   MODULE

account     include                    system-local-login
password    include                    system-local-login
session     optional                   pam_lastlog.so
session     include                    system-local-login

session     [default=1 success=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so uid > 0
session     optional                   MODULE PARAMs
```

muru's solution, based on the same principle of ignoring a given number of following rules is however nicer in that it uses a more dedicated module : pam_rootok.so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination of `success=1` and [`pam_rootok.so`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/pam_rootok.8.html) should work:

```
auth [success=1,default=ignore] pam_rootok.so
auth        optional    MODULE
```

From [`man 5 pam.conf`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/pam.conf.5.html):

```
For the more complicated syntax valid control values have the
following form:

         [value1=action1 value2=action2 ...]

Where valueN corresponds to the return code from the function
invoked in the module for which the line is defined.
... The actionN can take one of the following forms:
...

N (an unsigned integer)
   equivalent to ok with the side effect of jumping over the
   next N modules in the stack. Note that N equal to 0 is not
   allowed (and it would be identical to ok in such case).
```

So `success=1` should make PAM skip over `MODULE` if `pam_rootok.so` succeeds (which would be when the user is root).

Comment: Thanks @muru a lot for your attention and time. As edited in my question, I had found a way thanks to pam_succeed_if.so But your suggestion appears indeed nicer because more dedicated. => my vote.